# Creating github custom page

Tags: github, github-pages

First of all I am very new to github pages.

I am new to creating github custom pages, so i tried to create test page using https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/ and my repository url is https://github.com/mridulbirla/mridulbirla.github.io . I tried http://mridulbirla.github.io/index.html but it is giving me 404 error.

Can you please let me know where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a branch named gh-pages at your other project(For example the project name is "LeetCode").
Then you push the code to the project gh-pages branch.
Finally visit http://{username}.github.io/LeetCode .
The {username}.github.io project ,you can use it as you blog or personal home page.

Comment: I created new repository named mridulbirla.github.io and created a branch named gh-pages.

Comment: This project as your personal home page.You should push the code to master branch. If you want to create project page,you shoud go to the project and create the gh-pages branch.